# Don't believe everything you read?, Deprecated? or

Tags: android, android-contacts

A book ("Android Recipes" by Smith and Friesen) shows this:

```
public class ContactsListListActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
```

...yet not only was "AdapterView.OnItemClickListener" not available in Eclipse via New | Class | Interfaces ("Add" button) but when I added added "AdapterView.OnItemClickListener" it wasn't recognized ("AdapterView cannot be resolved to a type"). Is this deprecated, or...???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common error when working with `Object.OnXXXListener()` is that eclipse doesn't import it automatically.

You can easily fixed it manually by adding:

```
import android.widget.AdapterView;
```

As another note:

> [AdapterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) is not deprecated and it is already available since API 1.